# .htaccess rewriterule path not found while accessing through ip address

Tags: php, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting

I'm trying to set rewrite rule for my website through .htaccess. It works fine when access by domain name like -

http://www.example.com/admin/my/virtual/path

Problem is when I try to access through IP address, it returns 404 page.

I bind IP with my virtual path cause when I visit http://192.168.1.2/ it shows http://www.example.com/admin/ page i.e. home page of admin without any issue.

Following link doesn't work and returned 404 page -

http://192.168.1.2/my/virtual/path

I guess its .htaccess issue. Here is my .htaccess code FYI

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off
RewriteRule (.*) https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [R=301,L] 
# The following rule tells Apache that if the requested filename
# exists, simply serve it.
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -s [OR]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -l [OR]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -d
RewriteRule ^ index.php [L]
# The following rewrites all other queries to index.php. The 
# condition ensures that if you are using Apache aliases to do
# mass virtual hosting, the base path will be prepended to 
# allow proper resolution of the index.php file; it will work
# in non-aliased environments as well, providing a safe, one-size 
# fits all solution.
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI}::$1 ^(/.+)(.+)::\2$
RewriteRule ^(.*) - [E=BASE:%1]
RewriteRule ^([^?]*)$ %{ENV:BASE}index.php [NC,L]
```

Here is my vhost configuration for IP -

```
<VirtualHost xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx:80>
     DocumentRoot /path/of/my/hosting/location/public_html/admin
     <Directory "/path/of/my/hosting/location/public_html/admin">
         allow from all
         Options None
         Require all granted
     </Directory>
</VirtualHost>
```

Here is my domain hosting part -

```
<VirtualHost example.com:80>
    DocumentRoot /path/of/my/hosting/location/public_html
    <Directory "/path/of/my/hosting/location/public_html">
        allow from all
        Options +FollowSymLinks
        allowoverride all
        Require all granted
        HostNameLookups on
    </Directory>
    ServerName example.com
    ServerAlias www.example.com
</VirtualHost>
```

Comment: I'm almost sure it's related to the vhost and not the mod_rewrite. what is the content of your vhost?

Comment: it is not related vhost, cause i can access my index page through http://192.168.1.2/ and as well as through http://www.example.com/

Comment: did you check the logs on the server?

Comment: i forgot to check before, but i checked it now. nothing found. no log written. just access log found with 404 status

Comment: care to share the vhost config?

Comment: vhost configuration added FYI

Comment: where in the vhost you have the domain configured?

Comment: change a key point, i'm point a physical path called "admin" into IP

Comment: i think i got solution -

Options +FollowSymLinks
allowoverride all

these two line missing at IP vhost configuration. thanks to point vhost configuratoin @Dekel

Comment: did you check my answer from 3 minutes ago? :)

Comment: i just checked and accepted. :D

Comment: and btw, next time when someone ask for more info, just give it :) your comment "it is not related vhost" didn't really help to solve the issure here :) hehe

Comment: vote as you requested, i wasted 3 hours without checking hosting configuration properly... very sad!!!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The vhost part of the domain has `allowoverride all` inside, which tells apache to allow changes made `.htaccess`, however the vhost part of the ip don't have it.

Add the `allowoverride all` to the `ip` vhost-block and it should be ok.

```
<VirtualHost xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx:80>
     DocumentRoot /path/of/my/hosting/location/public_html/admin
     <Directory "/path/of/my/hosting/location/public_html/admin">
         allowoverride all
         allow from all
         Options None
         Require all granted
     </Directory>
</VirtualHost>
```